# Django form requires resubmission

Tags: python, html, django, django-forms, django-templates

I have a simple form in Django, and in my template I want to display each individual object for the whole queryset which I am saving the form to. The error I am getting is that my form does not seem to submit on the first attempt. Only when I click the submit button, manually refresh the page and then 'confirm form resubmission' do I see my updated queryset objects displayed in the template.

I am saving my form like this in my views:

```
 exercise_name = ExerciseName.objects.all()

 if request.method == 'POST':
      form = ExerciseNameForm(request.POST)
      if form.is_valid():
         form.save(commit=True)
      else:
         form = ExerciseNameForm()
```

and passing the queryset to the template through the following context:

```
{ 'exercise_name': exercise_name }
```

and iterating through it like

```
{% for exercise_title in exercise_name %}
  #content displaying each iteration 
{% endfor %}
```

with my form to update it like:

```
<div>
    <form method = "POST">{% csrf_token %}
        {{form.as_p}}
        <button type="submit" class="save btn btn-default">Save</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

I am not sure why it is making me refresh the page and resubmit the form again in order to see the updated queryset after submitting the form?

Answer (score 1):

You should be doing something like this:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = ExerciseNameForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save(commit=True)
        return HttpResponse("data submitted successfully") 
    else:
        return render(request, "your_template.html", {'form':form})
else: 
    form = ExerciseNameForm()
    return render(request, "your_template.html", {'form':form})
```